# Watch YouTube video with youtube_player_iframe Flutter

Tags: flutter, youtube-api, youtubeplayer

I would like to know how to open a YouTube video and showing it on my Flutter app with a video player that allow the user to stop the video, moving forward, backward just dragging the finger on the bottom line of the video.
I was thinking to use `youtube_player_iframe` since I read on the internet that this is the only widget that allows to open YouTube videos (for iOS, `youtube_player` for Android) so I installed it and copy-pasted the example from [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_iframe/example) and fixed some errors.

If anyone could help me to understand why it doesn't work I'll be very glad.

To install, from terminal run : `flutter pub add youtube_player_iframe`

Or just add the dependence : `youtube_player_iframe: ^2.0.0`

This is the code, just copy-paste and it can be run :

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_iframe/youtube_player_iframe.dart';
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(YoutubeApp());
}

///
class YoutubeApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Youtube Player IFrame Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: YoutubeAppDemo(),
    );
  }
}

///
class YoutubeAppDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _YoutubeAppDemoState createState() => _YoutubeAppDemoState();
}

class _YoutubeAppDemoState extends State<YoutubeAppDemo> {
  late YoutubePlayerController _controller;
  String urlVideoFromYouTube = 'v0RWej7Sqg4'; //this is the last part of the YouTube url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0RWej7Sqg4 copy-pasted by me

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: urlVideoFromYouTube,
      params: const YoutubePlayerParams(
        playlist: [
          'nPt8bK2gbaU',//Default playlist
          'K18cpp_-gP8',
          'iLnmTe5Q2Qw',
          '_WoCV4c6XOE',
          'KmzdUe0RSJo',
          '6jZDSSZZxjQ',
          'p2lYr3vM_1w',
          '7QUtEmBT_-w',
          '34_PXCzGw1M',
        ],
        startAt: const Duration(minutes: 1, seconds: 36),
        showControls: true,
        showFullscreenButton: true,
        desktopMode: true,
        privacyEnhanced: true,
        useHybridComposition: true,
      ),
    );
    _controller.onEnterFullscreen = () {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      ]);
      log('Entered Fullscreen');
    };
    _controller.onExitFullscreen = () {
      log('Exited Fullscreen');
    };
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const player = YoutubePlayerIFrame();
    return YoutubePlayerControllerProvider(
      // Passing controller to widgets below.
      controller: _controller,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Youtube Player IFrame'),
        ),
        body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            if (kIsWeb && constraints.maxWidth > 800) {
              return Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const Expanded(child: player),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 500,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Controls(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
            return ListView(
              children: [
                player,
                const Controls(),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

///
class Controls extends StatelessWidget {
  ///
  const Controls();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          // _space,
          // MetaDataSection(),
          // _space,
          // SourceInputSection(),
          // _space,
          // PlayPauseButtonBar(),
          // _space,
          // VolumeSlider(),
          // _space,
          // PlayerStateSection(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get _space => const SizedBox(height: 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the link to that repository: https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_iframe, download it fully and run it's main.dart file using VS code or android studio, You can't run just a main.dart file without the other files for this plugin to work.Doing this, will give you an idea of how to run this plugin.